# Recursive function that return the output from a given input

Tags: algorithm, function, recursion

I need to write algorithmic recursive functions that returns the output according to the tables below

```
Input:  0 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8
Output: 1 1 2 4 7 13 24 44 81

Input:  0 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8  9  10  11
Output: 0 0 0 1 1 0  1  1  0  1  1   0
```

any Ideas?

Comment: The first is the sum of the 3 previous terms, the second... Dunno. Anyway WTF?

Comment: `000` then `110` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for the first example the rule for evaluation is actually "return the sum of the previous three elements", the function could be implemented in C#, C++ or Java as follows.

```
int f(int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 || n == 1 )
        return 1;
    else if ( n == 2 )
        return 2;
    else return f(n-3) + f(n-2) + f(n-1);
}
```

The second function could be implemented as follows.

```
int f(int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2 )
        return 0;
    else if ( n == 3 || n == 4 )
        return 1;
    else return f(n-3);
}
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. Is the answer too straightforward?

Comment: Might be because you've just given an implementation without explaining the solution (or even the principles of recursive functions)?